# image file not found 404 error

Tags: jquery, python, flask

following this tutorial for flask for loading jquery. 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/
i write bellow code in index.html which resides in template folder and outside of template i have test.py file

```
<img src="start.jpeg" alt="start"/>
```

start.jpeg is also available in template folder where index.html is available. when i run python test.py file i'm getting bellow error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jul/2013 19:27:45] "GET /start.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404
```

even i faced same problem for jquery file. if i download jquery.js file and put it in js folder

```
src="js/jquery.js"
```

instead of importing google cdn file then also i'm getting same error.
please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `url_for` in your template, which is [the recommended way](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#static-files) to access static files with Flask.

Put your image in:

```
/static/start.jpeg
```

And use:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='start.jpeg') }}" alt="start"/>
```